# Match world if there is no special char - Regex using C#

Tags: c#, regex

How to match these string: Ks 1

I have used this pattern  `^((?!\*).)*$`!

```
Ks 1*, Zs 3v "6"
Ks 1 (/R)
Ks 1* Zs 3v "6"
Ks 1, (/R)*
```

The match that I want:

```
Ks 1 (/R)
Ks 1, (/R)*
```

Comment: Maybe you meant the cases where `*` precedes the digit? `^(?:(?!\d\*).)*$` - see [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cd%5c*%29.%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=Ks+1*%2c+Zs+3v+%226%22%0d%0aKs+1+%28%2fR%29%0d%0aKs+1*+Zs+3v+%226%22%0d%0aKs+1%2c+%28%2fR%29*&o=m).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, but I want to match "Ks 1" but no "Ks 1*"

Comment: Right, see [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cd%5c*%29.%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=Ks+1*%2c+Zs+3v+%226%22%0d%0aKs+1+%28%2fR%29%0d%0aKs+1*+Zs+3v+%226%22%0d%0aKs+1%2c+%28%2fR%29*&o=m). The line with `Ks 1*` is not matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. That is what I want! Could we make to match just "Ks 1". The pattern match and others string for example "Ks 2", but I want just "Ks 1" without "*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^(?!.*\d\*).*
^(?:(?!\d\*).)*$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%5Cd%5C*%29.%29*%5Cr%3F%24&i=Ks%201*%2C%20Zs%203v%20%226%22%0D%0AKs%201%20%28%2FR%29%0D%0AKs%201*%20Zs%203v%20%226%22%0D%0AKs%201%2C%20%28%2FR%29*&o=m). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\d\*)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are any zero or more chars other than a newline char as many as possible and then a digit and a `*` char
- `(?:(?!\d\*).)*` - a single char other than a newline char, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a digit + `*` char sequence
- `.*` - the rest of the line.
- `$` - end of string.

And if you plan to match `Ks` and a number after it that has no `*` right after, you can use

```cs
\bKs\s*\d+\b(?!\*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbKs%5Cs*%5Cd%2B%5Cb%28%3F!%5C*%29&i=Ks%201*%2C%20Zs%203v%20%226%22%0D%0AKs%201%20%28%2FR%29%0D%0AKs%201*%20Zs%203v%20%226%22%0D%0AKs%201%2C%20%28%2FR%29*&o=m). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Ks` - a string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\*)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `*` immediately on the right.

Comment: Could we make to match just "Ks 1". The pattern match and others string for example "Ks 2", but I want just "Ks 1" without "*" ?

Comment: @DevOp `\bKs\s*\d+\b(?!\*)`?